# How to combine these two expl3-based functions to show the day of week in English?

Tags: expl3, datetime

I wrote a function `\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn` to calculate the "day of week" given the year, month and day (the algorithm adopted should work for dates after 1800s), and also a function `\projlib_datetime_display_week_english:n` to convert a given number from 1 to 7 to English words. However, I don't know how to combine them to show the day of week of a given date in English. I thought `\exp_args:Ne` would be enough for getting the value of the first one and then passing to the second, but it doesn't.

Below is my code. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{projlib-datetime}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_day_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_month_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
\cs_new:Nn \projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_day_int { #3 }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #2 } < { 3 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } }
      }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int { #1 }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int { \int_eval:n { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int / 100 } }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int { \int_mod:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int } { 100 } }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_month_int
      {
        \int_case:nnF { #2 }
          {
            {  1 } { 0 }
            {  2 } { 3 }
            {  3 } { 2 }
            {  4 } { 5 }
            {  5 } { 0 }
            {  6 } { 3 }
            {  7 } { 5 }
            {  8 } { 1 }
            {  9 } { 4 }
            { 10 } { 6 }
            { 11 } { 2 }
            { 12 } { 4 }
          }        { 0 }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
      {
        \int_eval:n
          {
              \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_day_int
            + \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_month_int
            +\l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int } { 4 }
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int } { 4 }
            - 2 * \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int
          }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
      {
        \int_mod:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int } { 7 }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int } < { 1 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
          {
            \int_eval:n { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int + 7 }
          }
      }
    \int_use:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
  }



\cs_new:Nn \projlib_datetime_display_week_english:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { 1 }  { Monday    }
        { 2 }  { Tuesday   }
        { 3 }  { Wednesday }
        { 4 }  { Thursday  }
        { 5 }  { Friday    }
        { 6 }  { Saturday  }
        { 7 }  { Sunday    }
      } { ??? }
  }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 02 } { 16 }

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 02 } { 28 }

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 03 } { 01 }

% \exp_args:Ne
% \projlib_datetime_display_week_english:n
%   {
%     \projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 02 } { 01 }
%   }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: `e` argument is _expansion_ actually the `\expanded` primitive, so like `\edef` so it can only expand expandable macros but your function does assignments so can not be expandable and can not work in an  context

Comment: If you removed the`\int_use:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int` from theend then calling the first would leave theresul it `\l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int` which you could then pass to your second function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written your first function is not expandable so can not be used in an expansion context such as `e` argument. You could write it to be expandable by removing all the internal assignments, but simpler is remove the final `\use` so the result is just left in the local variable, which you can then either use or pass to your second function as required.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{projlib-datetime}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_day_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_month_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int
\int_new:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
\cs_new:Nn \projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_day_int { #3 }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #2 } < { 3 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } }
      }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int { #1 }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int { \int_eval:n { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int / 100 } }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int { \int_mod:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int } { 100 } }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_month_int
      {
        \int_case:nnF { #2 }
          {
            {  1 } { 0 }
            {  2 } { 3 }
            {  3 } { 2 }
            {  4 } { 5 }
            {  5 } { 0 }
            {  6 } { 3 }
            {  7 } { 5 }
            {  8 } { 1 }
            {  9 } { 4 }
            { 10 } { 6 }
            { 11 } { 2 }
            { 12 } { 4 }
          }        { 0 }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
      {
        \int_eval:n
          {
              \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_day_int
            + \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_month_int
            +\l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_year_int } { 4 }
            + \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int } { 4 }
            - 2 * \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_century_int
          }
      }
    \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
      {
        \int_mod:nn { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int } { 7 }
      }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int } < { 1 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
          {
            \int_eval:n { \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int + 7 }
          }
      }
%    \int_use:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int
  }



\cs_new:Nn \projlib_datetime_display_week_english:n
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { 1 }  { Monday    }
        { 2 }  { Tuesday   }
        { 3 }  { Wednesday }
        { 4 }  { Thursday  }
        { 5 }  { Friday    }
        { 6 }  { Saturday  }
        { 7 }  { Sunday    }
      } { ??? }
  }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 02 } { 16 }
\int_use:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int

\par\bigskip

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 02 } { 28 }
\int_use:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int

\par\bigskip

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 03 } { 01 }
\int_use:N \l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int

\par\bigskip

\projlib_datetime_calculate_day_of_week_with_year_month_day:nnn { 2022 } { 02 } { 01 }
\projlib_datetime_display_week_english:n\l__projlib_datetime_day_of_week_result_int


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```